# polymer core-list with core-ajax data

Tags: polymer

I am trying to use Polymer's core-list with data from a core-ajax source.
I tried something like:

```
<polymer-element name="my-list-test">
  <template>
    <core-ajax url="http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments" auto
               handleAs="json" 
               response="{{mydata}}"></core-ajax>

    <core-list data="{{mydata}}" class="mylist" flex>
       <template>
          <div layout horizontal>
             <div>{{model.id}} - {{model.email}} {{model.name}}</div>
          </div>
       </template>
    </core-list>
  </template>
  <script>
     Polymer({
     });
  </script>
</polymer-element>
```

I find this partially works. The data source has 500 items but the core-list shows only 12 items at a time. When I try to go back, it stops before reaching the first one, usually on line 23. Can someone help me figure this out?

Thanks for any help

Comment: Hope this article helps: https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/elements/core-elements.html#core-list

Comment: Yes, I've read it. But I confess tha I could not understand how to use all the information properly. Still clueless. I think there is a lack of practical examples.

Answer (score 0):

Warp the core-list in a conditional template:

```
 <template if='{{mydata}}'>
   <core-list data="{{mydata}}" class="mylist" flex>
    <template>
      <div layout horizontal>
         <div>{{model.id}} - {{model.email}} {{model.name}}</div>
      </div>
    </template>
   </core-list>
</template>
```

This is to ensure that core-list element wont be created prior the data bound is ready.

Answer (score 0):

This seem to be a bug in core-list and here's a little workaround.
This bug seem to disappear when you bind the `index` value of the array to something.

```
<template if='{{mydata}}'>
   <core-list data="{{mydata}}" class="mylist" flex>
    <template>
      <div layout horizontal>
         <div data-index={{index}}>{{model.id}} - {{model.email}} {{model.name}}</div>
      </div>
    </template>
   </core-list>
</template>
```

`data-index` is a totally made up attribute just to use the `{{index}}` variable.

Please watch this video by Google below it illustrates this fix.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2UKPRbrw3Kk

Link to GitHub issue of this Bug:
https://github.com/Polymer/core-list/issues/62

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure you have a height attribute and a height in the style, I think. I had the same issue as you, and adding this fixed it:

```
<core-list data="{{data}}" height="20" style="height:100%">
```

Hope this helps.